# How do I resolve "wasn't able to locate a file for the libpango1.0-0 package"?

Tags: 12.04, pango

This message came up while trying to Install (software) Updates the Update Manager said "are available for this computer".

I have no idea what "the libpango1.0-0 package" is, nor how it relates to any of the Updates (I'm a total newbie, having only recently bought, and turned on, a machine pre-loaded with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS).

Answer (score 1):

It may be a dependent package. If software update failed. Then you can try it with terminal. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.
Type or copy/paste with mouse or keyboard. You can paste into terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>.

`sudo apt-get clean` to clean previous software cache. Remember you have to provide your password when promoted. Password field will stay blank when you enter password....don't worry about it. Just enter password and press <kbd>enter</kbd>

`sudo apt-get -f install` to solve any dependency problem.

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to update your softwarelist and upgrade all software component that have a new version available.

By this `upgrade` command your kernel will not upgrade. So you have to type `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Comment: Thanks! I decided to click on "Install Updates" again - the message I'd gotten (that my question is about) was several days ago - and, magically, everything worked fine! Including the absence of the "Requires installation of untrusted packages" message I got last time!!